# Query Selector for data - Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, queryselector

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("briefsectiontop").querySelector("[data=" + i + "]").getElementsByClassName("current")[0];
if (elem.style.display == "none") {
  elem.style.display = "block";
} else {
  elem.style.display = "none";
};
```

There are other div elements, but that should be enough to know what the essential HTML looks like, why won't it take my query?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection (array-like structure), not an individual element. Collections don't have a `querySelector()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value being searched for must be enclosed in quotes if it starts with a number, or contains any characters which aren't alphanumeric:

```
.querySelector(`[data="${i}"]`)
```

But `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, not a single element, so you can't call `querySelector` on it.

Instead, consider using just a *single call* of `querySelector`:

```
const elm = document.querySelector(`.briefsectiontop [data="${i}"] .current`);
```

This will select a `.current` element with an ancestor with the `data` attribute you're looking for, which also has an ancestor element with a `briefsectiontop` class name. CSS selectors allow for wonderfully concise ways of identifying elements.

```js
const i = 3;
const elm = document.querySelector(`.briefsectiontop [data="${i}"] .current`);
console.log(elm);
```

```html
<div class="briefsectiontop">
  <div data="3">
    <div class="current">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```